# Is there a clean way to define a custom setter and getter on a class or object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

Is there a proper way to define a custom setter or getter on an object or class in JavaScript or TypeScript so that the resulting variable returns a value when accessed, but also has a `set()` method for setting the value of the variable?

Here's what I mean :

```js
const theVariable = customGetSet([someVariable, setterFn]);
console.log(theVariable); // 'hello'

// set a new value
theVariable.set('wow');
// or better yet
theVariable('wow');

console.log(theVariable); // 'wow'
```

The reason I cannot use the assignment operator is that I am using this with React and want to use this with state variables (`useState`) inside a context (state variables must be set with their setter function).

Here's what I've got so far (note that if nothing is passed to `State()`, it returns a placeholder that does nothing) :

```js
type StateUpdater <T> = Dispatch<SetStateAction<T>>;
type SetState <T> = [T, StateUpdater<T>];
type StateType<T> = () => T & {
    set: StateUpdater<T>;
};

export function State <T> (stateData?: SetState<T>) {
    const f = function () {
        return stateData?stateData[0]:undefined;
    }
    f.prototype.set = function (value) {
        (stateData?stateData[1]:((value) => undefined) as StateUpdater<T>)(value);
    } as StateUpdater <T>;
    return f as StateType<T>;
}
```

It can be used like this:

```js
const theState = useState(0);
const theVariable = State(theState);
console.log(theVariable()); // 0
theVariable.set(2); // changes the value to 2
```

Which works just fine. However, you need to call `theVariable` it to get the value. I would like to be able to simply access the variable to get the value (like normal) while still having the `.set()` functionality. So, like this (as at the start of the question):

```js
const theState = useState(0);
const theVariable = State(theState);
console.log(theVariable); // 0
theVariable.set(2); // changes the value to 2
// Or, as above, better yet:
theVariable(2); // set the value to 2
```

It's a minor detail, but I'd like to know if it's possible.

Comment: I don't think this is possible. Properties can have get/set handlers, but *variables* cannot.  Do you want `theVariable(2)` to make `theVariable === 2` true, and then `theVariable(4)` makes `theVariable === 4` true?  You *might* be able to get this done by making `theVariable` a property of `window` or something, but that wouldn't work if `theVariable` is a `const`.

Comment: @jcalz pretty much, yes. either that or `theVariable.set(2)`, etc.

Comment: Then it's impossible; if `theVariable === 2` then it will by necessity not have a `set` property or be callable (you're not going to find something to strictly equal a number unless it's a number).  You're going to have to seek a different approach.  I could write this up as an answer, but "nope" isn't very exciting.

Comment: @jcalz ok then thanks for that :) . I'll stick to he function-based approach.